# How do I loop back to the start of an 'if' branch?

Tags: c#

I want to loop back to the beginning of the 'if' condition if the 'else' condition is met. I'm really new to C# programming and struggling quite a bit if I'm honest. Sorry if this has been asked before, I *did* search but found nothing.

---

Here's my (messy) code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tinkering
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let's go on an adventure shall we?\n\nLet's start with your name:");
                string userName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("\nHi " + userName);
                Console.WriteLine("\nIs that a girls' name?\n");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("\nI see\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Well anyway, let's get started shall we?\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you care to go Left or Right " + userName);

                while (userInput)
                {

                    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userInput == "left")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Left it is!\nYou see a long dark corridor. There is a sudden empty feeling in your stomach, kind of like that weird feeling where it feels empty but you know you could shit...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    else if (userInput == "right")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ok let's head right\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("\nIt looks as though we have a locked door here...");
                        Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately" + userName);
                        Console.WriteLine("that is the end of this shitty little game (I couldn't be bothered writing anymore code for it lol");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Just type 'left' or 'right' please");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How does using a string as your condition for the `while` work exactly? I'm guessing syntax error?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. you have it in a while loop (though a very weird one), so it will repeat when it hits the closing `}`. Perhaps you just need to fix your condition (which doesn't even look like it would compile)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I learned a few things online and decided to tinker/fool around a bit (as a friend says that's the best thing for learning programming...) but obviously I need to go back to the very beginning...

Comment: Does this even compile? Also you could do while (true)

Comment: while is best used for booleans then? or?

Comment: And yeah, it compiles with all the conditions...not in it's current state (with the 'while' there

Comment: Kenny, read [this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx). Seems like there is a lack of some basic C# concepts. And yes. while is ONLY for boolean conditions. You can compare for equality though (boolean result)

Comment: Just struggling and desperate to learn this stuff. I find a lot of tutorials online define the language terminology but do not define then show how it can be used/practicality...

I'm supposed to be going to college in September to learn this stuff and I wanted to give myself the best possible chance to comprehend it...

Comment: Thanks a lot DangerZone, didn't really want to post this to be honest for fear of ridicule lol

Thank you all

Comment: Honestly, don't jump in with too much to handle. Focus on a single topic, maybe write a small program to prove that you taught yourself, and work it into bigger applications. And don't worry about college, you'll have years to practice small things like this.

Comment: Thanks, I find it fascinating writing something into an IDE and watching it come to life. 

Just need to expose myself relentlessy to get it through my skull I suppose...

Comment: Expose myself to code....not to old ladies in the park from under a raincoat I mean

Answer (score 1):

You are using `console.ReadLine()` at the begginning of while loop. So delete them from the end of if block,else if block and else block. Then your code should automatically go back to the if statement

```
 while (userInput)
            {
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput == "left")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Left it is!\nYou see a long dark corridor. There is a sudden empty feeling in your stomach, kind of like that weird feeling where it feels empty but you know you could shit...");
                }

                else if (userInput == "right")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ok let's head right\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIt looks as though we have a locked door here...");
                    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately" + userName);
                    Console.WriteLine("that is the end of this shitty little game (I couldn't be bothered writing anymore code for it lol");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Just type 'left' or 'right' please");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `while` condition works correctly, you'd add `break;` at the end of your `"left"` and `"right"` cases.  This will break you out of the loop and move on.

A simple scenario would be something like this:

```
string userInput;
while (true){
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userInput == "left"){
        //do stuff
        break;
    } else if (userInput == "right"){
        //do stuff
        break;
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic community, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Best practices are to also: a) use Swtich vs. If Statement and b) avoid Literal Constants.  The Block End Comments are a rare "best practice", but I've personally found they significantly increase readability when used and vice versa (esp. in legacy code with "worst practice" "'long'" Blocks).

Ex.

```
        const string Direction_Left = "left";
        const string Direction_Right = "right";

        string userInput;

        while (true)
        {

            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (userInput)
            {

                case Direction_Left:
                {
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                } // case Direction_Left:

                case Direction_Right:
                {
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                } // case Direction_Right:

                default:
                {
                    //do stuff
                    continue;
                } // default:

            } // switch (userInput)

        } // while (true)
```